STM32 TAMP REG Debugger clearing
I'm using an STM32L4P5, which has TAMP registers in the backup domain.
For some reason, every time I reconnect or power off/reconnect the debugger to the device, the tamp registers are clearing.  Is there any known cause or workaround?
Here is the MX_RTC_init code, note that  if (LL_RCC_GetRTCClockSource() != LL_RCC_RTC_CLKSOURCE_LSE) { doesn't resolve true in the debugger, so I know its not calling the domain reset when this happens.
static void MX_RTC_Init(void) {

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */

  LL_RTC_InitTypeDef RTC_InitStruct = { 0 };
  LL_RTC_TimeTypeDef RTC_TimeStruct = { 0 };
  LL_RTC_DateTypeDef RTC_DateStruct = { 0 };

  if (LL_RCC_GetRTCClockSource() != LL_RCC_RTC_CLKSOURCE_LSE) {
    FlagStatus pwrclkchanged = RESET;
    /* Update LSE configuration in Backup Domain control register */
    /* Requires to enable write access to Backup Domain if necessary */
    if (LL_APB1_GRP1_IsEnabledClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_PWR) != 1U) {
      /* Enables the PWR Clock and Enables access to the backup domain */
      LL_APB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_PWR);
      pwrclkchanged = SET;
    }
    if (LL_PWR_IsEnabledBkUpAccess() != 1U) {
      /* Enable write access to Backup domain */
      LL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
      while (LL_PWR_IsEnabledBkUpAccess() == 0U) {
      }
    }
    LL_RCC_ForceBackupDomainReset();
    LL_RCC_ReleaseBackupDomainReset();
    LL_RCC_LSE_SetDriveCapability(LL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_HIGH);
    LL_RCC_LSE_Enable();

    /* Wait till LSE is ready */
    while (LL_RCC_LSE_IsReady() != 1) {
    }
    LL_RCC_SetRTCClockSource(LL_RCC_RTC_CLKSOURCE_LSE);
    /* Restore clock configuration if changed */
    if (pwrclkchanged == SET) {
      LL_APB1_GRP1_DisableClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_PWR);
    }
  }

  /* Peripheral clock enable */
  LL_RCC_EnableRTC();
  LL_APB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_RTCAPB);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

/* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */
/** Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date
 */

  RTC_InitStruct.HourFormat = LL_RTC_HOURFORMAT_24HOUR;
  /* Settings notes */
  /* 32768 / (31 + 1) == 1024 .. 0x3FF + 1 == 1024 */
  /* 1024 sec */
  RTC_InitStruct.AsynchPrescaler = 31;
  RTC_InitStruct.SynchPrescaler = 0x3FF;

  if (TAMP->BKP31R != 0x32F2) {
    LL_RTC_Init(RTC, &RTC_InitStruct);
    /* Set global flag to indicate time is not set */
    rtccBackupWasDead = 1;
    RTC_TimeStruct.Hours = 0;
    RTC_TimeStruct.Minutes = 0;
    RTC_TimeStruct.Seconds = 0;
    LL_RTC_TIME_Init(RTC, LL_RTC_FORMAT_BIN, &RTC_TimeStruct);
    RTC_DateStruct.WeekDay = LL_RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
    RTC_DateStruct.Month = LL_RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
    RTC_DateStruct.Year = 20;
    LL_RTC_DATE_Init(RTC, LL_RTC_FORMAT_BIN, &RTC_DateStruct);
    TAMP->BKP31R = 0x32F2;
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */
  LL_RTC_DisableWriteProtection(RTC);
  LL_RTC_EnableShadowRegBypass(RTC);
  LL_RTC_EnableWriteProtection(RTC);
  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */
}


What does the Technical reference manual for stm32l4p say about the TAMP registers?

@MrGerber you'll have to clarify, there is a chapter about it, I've read the chapter, nothing is presently standing out about this issue.  No reset causes approximate what I've listed.
